# Insert missing values with nested loop

Tags: mysql, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I have a table of `events` that includes the year, number of attendees and the location which it looks up the location from the `location` table.

**tbl_events**

```
+-----+--------------+------+-----------+--------+
| ID  |  LOCATION_ID | YEAR | ATTENDEES | RATING |
+-----+--------------+------+-----------+--------+
| 1   | 1            | 2014 | 44        | 6      |
| 2   | 2            | 2014 | 36        | 7      |
| 3   | 4            | 2014 | 51        | 7      |
| ... | ...          | ...  | ...       | ...    |
| 74  | 2            | 2015 | 59        | 6.5    |
| 75  | 4            | 2015 | 31        | 5      |
| 76  | 12           | 2015 | 66        | 8      |
| ... | ...          | ...  | ...       | ...    |
| 133 | 5            | 2016 | 71        | 8.5    |
| 134 | 32           | 2016 | 68        | 6.5    |
| 135 | 14           | 2016 | 59        | 7.5    |
| ... | ...          | ...  | ...       | ...    |
+-----+--------------+------+-----------+--------+
```

**tbl_locations**

```
+-----+-------------+
| ID  |    Name     |
+-----+-------------+
| 1   | Falmouth    |
| 2   | Plymouth    |
| 3   | Exeter      |
| 4   | Bristol     |
| 5   | Bournemouth |
| 6   | Southampton |
| ... | ...         |
| 99  | Edinburgh   |
| 100 | Glasgow     |
+-----+-------------+
```

I've only got records of events that happened, which includes the required information of year, location, attendees and rating.

I'd like to add rows of missing values, to include all of the locations from the `locations` table for all of the years in the table.

So I think (ideally) I need to nest a loop that runs through the table for each year, and loop through all of the locations in the `location` table, and inserts the missing rows either directly into the `events` table, or into a temp table which I can then insert into the events table after.

The alternative that I thought of joining the events and locations tables with years, and inserting into a temp table. Then insert into the events table, all of the rows that aren't in the events table.

Any other ideas are welcome, but I'm limited to doing this in MySQL only.

Ideally I can save it as a procedure and re-run it later on.

Comment: **I'd like to add rows of missing values, to include all of the locations from the locations table for all of the years in the table.** can you be more clear with this sentence.

Comment: Not every event is visited every year. But I'd still like a row in the table, so it would have ID, location_id, year, then NULL for attendees and rating.

Answer (score 0):

You could `cross join` the locations and all the years to get a full set of combinations. Them, just left join them on the actual events so you get rows with `null`s (or some other custom value) in the slots where events are missing:

```
SELECT     e.*
FROM       tbl_locations l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM events) y 
LEFT JOIN  events e ON l.id = e.location_id AND y.year = e.year
```